# Cancel UIButton touch while touching it

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have a situation where a user would be touching a UIButton and while they might already be touching it, I need to be able to cancel it or cause it to fail.

I have tried to use button.enabled and userInteractionEnabled, but neither one works on the fly. Both have to be set before the touch begins.

Can I cause the button to fail after and while it is being touched?

Comment: are you trying to cancel a background process or the direct outlet connected to the button ?

Answer (score 11):

You need to register two actions for your button, one for touch down and one for touch up. In touch down, you can decide if you want to cancel; and in touch up, write the actual logic for button press.

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(touchDown:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown]; 

- (IBAction)touchDown:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *b = (UIButton*)sender;

    // Call this if you wish to cancel the event tracking
    [b cancelTrackingWithEvent:nil];
}
```

For reference, see [the documentation of `-cancelTrackingWithEvent:` in `UIControl`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618219-canceltrackingwithevent?language=objc).

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do to solve your issue is to customize the pressed appearance of the button to your needs. Use: 
`– setBackgroundImage:@"NormalStateImage.png" forState: UIControlStateNormal`
`– setBackgroundImage:@"HighlightedStateImage.png" forState: UIControlStateHighlighted`

set the property `adjustsImageWhenHighlighted` to NO
and the `adjustsImageWhenDisabled` property to NO

Comment: This is my present workaround, but it seems that I should be able to cancel the touch somehow.

Comment: you are able to cancel the touch. But you have to handle them differently. You have to implement `UIResponder`'s Responding to Touch Events. Check this Apple doc http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html and this tutorial http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-quick-tip-detecting-touches/

Comment: Wouldn't something like hitTest be simpler?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done for any `UIButton`. If you want to cancel the button press at the time the user touches down on it, these steps should work:

1. Set up the handler for the events where the cancellation needs to be checked. In this case, when the button is down.

   ```
   [yourButton addTarget: self
                  action: @selector(buttonIsDownHandler:)
        forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDown];
   ```
2. In the handler, decide whether to cancel the press

   ```
   -(IBAction) buttonIsDownHandler: (id) sender
   {
      if (needToCancelThisPress)
      {
         [yourButton cancelTrackingWithEvent: nil];
      }
   }
   ```
3. The button’s handler for `UIControlEventTouchCancel` will be called after the cancellation.

The button touch cancellation can be done at any time. For example, if you want to track when the user presses and holds for too long, you could start a timer in the `UIControlEventTouchDown` handler, and then cancel the touch when the timer expires.

Answer (score 0):

Just have BOOL variable which points either button action is allowed or not and check where necessary. Enabled and userinteractionenabled is just to disable touches in general

Comment: But how can I cancel touches after the button is already being pushed? With a bool I can keep the touch from doing anything but it will still show that it is being touched.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your problem but you can have differant actions based on control event like below

```
[button addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(onTouchUpInside:)
           forControlEvents:(UIControlEventTouchUpInside)]; 

[button addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(onTouchDown:)
           forControlEvents:(UIControlEventTouchDown)]; 

[button addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(onTouchUpOutside:)
           forControlEvents:(UIControlEventTouchUpOutside)];
```

Please excuse me if it is not helpful or what you are looking for.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but I'm not sure that's what I'm after.